# Find all solutions for the equation $x^2-3y^2=17$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all solutions for the equation $x^2-3y^2=17$.

I approached the problem by considering the equation modulo $17$. We get that $$x^2-3y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{17} \iff x^2 \equiv 3y^2 \pmod{17}$$

Now I noted that the quadratic residues modulo $17$ are $1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16$ none of which are a multiple of $3$ and some integer squared. I therefore concluded that the equation has no solutions.

I found out a solution for the problem which used modulo $3$, but I wonder if the approach I took is correct or is there a flaw?

Comment: One mistake you made is when you concluded 

"Now I noted that the quadratic residues modulo 17 are 1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16 none of which are a multiple of 3 and some integer squared."

This is incorrect: 9 is a multiple of three and an integer squared.

First I would look at the multiple of threes: which are 9 and 15. Which means that suitable candidates for x are 3,7,10 and 14 modulo 17. From there you note that gcd(3,17) is 1 ...

Comment: This is a _generalized_ [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

Comment: This is correct, but if you use the same method for mod 3, and realize $x^2$ mod(3) is never equivalent to 17, you would have to take significantly less steps

Comment: I believe when Johansen wrote "multiple of 3 and some integer squared", Johansen really meant "product of 3 and some integer squared". None of given quadratic residues can be multiplied by 3 to get another quadratic residue. But maybe Johansen forgot about quadratic residue 0.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu This is what I meant... Do we need to consider $0$? I've read that we actually don't consider zero since it's a special case.

Comment: @Johansen Welcome to Math SE.  FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2-3y%5E2%3D17%24&p=1), I found [How to prove that the equation $x^2-3y^2=17$ has no integer solutions?](/q/276904/602049).

Comment: @John Omelian Therefore you should mark the present issue as duplicated of the one you just found.

Comment: @JeanMarie The OP specifically was asking about their attempt using modulo $17$, rather than modulo $3$ as used in the answer to that linked question, and the OP here even stated they found a solution using modulo $3$. As such, I didn't consider that the linked post answered the specific question the OP was asking about, so I didn't vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially right. You showed by exhaustion that $3$ is not a quadratic residue of $17$.

But

> none of [the residues] are a multiple of 3 and some integer squared

is not the way to say that.

Note: if there were integer solutions there would be infinitely many since you could construct them from solutions to the Pell equation $x^2 - 3y^2 = 1$.